# OSX Localization - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to setup some basic localization via XCode.

I have done the following:

1. Added a new Localize.strings file.
2. Added French to my applications localization settings.[image: French]The one localized file is the Localize.strings file.
3. I have added an 'Open File' localized string to my Localize.strings file.[image: Localized Strings]
4. I have created an outlet, linked it to a button and added the following code:

Code (could not figure out how to get this inline with the bullet):

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
    [openButton setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Open File", nil)];
}
```

My `openButton` is NOT null.

I have moved French (Francais) to be the prefered language in the language and text system preference. I launch the application and the title is localized, but my button is not!

[image: Screenshot]

Am I missing something stupid? Did I do something wrong here? From the tutorials I have read, this should do the trick, but it does not seem to be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a semicolon after your "Open File" line in the screenshot you posted. That will make the strings file invalid.

EDIT: The complete answer is that, in addition to the missing semicolon, `NSLocalizedString` looks for a file named "Localizable.strings", and in this case, the file was named "Localize.strings". To load localized strings from a file with a different name, you need to use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`. In this case, the call would be `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Open File", @"Localize", nil);`.

See Apple's [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-97055-CJBFDJGF) for the full documentation on how `NSLocalizedString` et. al. look for strings in files.

Comment: Hrrm, I've added the semicolon in each of the `Localize.strings` but, the app still shows like this: http://imgur.com/NUb0Hr9. I also did a `NSLog(@"Test: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Open File", nil));` and it still comes out as "Open File".

Comment: I just noticed that your file is named "Localize.strings". I believe the correct file name is "Localizable.strings", and I believe the filename does matter. If you're on 10.8 or later, the name of the enclosing lproj folder in your app's Resources directory matters too. It needs to be "fr.lproj", and not "French.lproj".

Comment: Yep, renaming the file did it. Thats crazy. Thanks for the help!